# Jquery datepicker - different day/week/month order in the input field?

Tags: jquery, html, input, datepicker

I have a datepicker in my document that inputs a date into the input field it's attached to once you click on a day, as it should. my problem is that I'd like to change the order in which that date is shown. for example, at the moment it reads

11/21/2012 (mm/dd/yyyy)

When I select the 21st of November 2012 when I need it to show

2012/11/21 (yyyy/mm/dd)

is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is one of the options when you setup the datepicker Take a look here for options:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

I believe the option you want is the following:

```
dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
```

Comment: one last question; do you know how to use dashes instead of forward slashes?

Comment: just for others to know, the answer to that would be "yy-mm-dd".

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible, you can find it here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats